# JavaScript setTimeout not workig as expected

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a code sample

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   setTimeout() {
      console.log("i " + i)
}
}
```

This is printing "3" to the console three times. However, I want it to print "0, 1, 2" **without using let.**

So far, I have tried the following -

```
 var funcs = [];
        function createfunc(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log("i ", i)
        }
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        setTimeout(() => {
           funcs[i] = createfunc(i) // statement 1
        }, 1000)
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
           funcs[j]();

        }
```

This is working fine if I use the statement 1 just as it is without putting it into the setTimeout function. However, it is throwing an error if I'm using the setTimeout function. Can someone let me know how can I make print 0, 1, 2 to the console using the setTimeout function ?

Comment: _"However, it is throwing an error if I'm using the setTimeout function"_ - Because you're using `setTimeout` wrong (at least in the first example) -> [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), anyway you can use the below codes, then you will be getting the proper result that you want.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ((i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("i " + i)
    }, 0);
  })(i);
}
```